# ScrollView in tabbed activity jumps down

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview, android-tabbed-activity

I was making an xkcd explain reader app.

I started off with a tabbed activity, pre-genned by idea. Then I changed the fragment's xml to have a scrollview with my actual layout in it.

Then however things did not work fully as expected, every time I change to another tab (/fragment) it renders correctly but after a second my scrollview will jump down a bit (scrollbar not the actuall scrollview).

Gif of action: [Android screen capture showing the issue](https://i.imgur.com/qBF0QcF.gifv)

If there is any extra information required please tell me.

EDIT: Some people sugested to change the scrollview to a nestedscrollview. This didn't fix my issue.

*The fragment's xml:*

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="com.henrykvdb.xkcdexplain.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Title"
                android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Desc"
                android:id="@+id/descTextView"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:contentDescription="xkcd"/>
        <WebView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/explainWebView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

*My activity_main's xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.henrykvdb.xkcdexplain.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Just an FYI I tried to add your image to the post, but because it is a GIF it was displaying as a broken image.

Comment: Okay, didn't know I couldn't use gifs. I'm still pretty new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to my LinearLayout fixed everything.

Comment: I can't accept it yet. After posting the answer yourself there is a 24 hour cooldown before you can accept it. @ToddSewell

Comment: Not fixed fully but there's a little improvement after adding this suggestion.